# How do I change the color of / darken the axis of 'Scatter Plot' in Python Orange (Vis)

Tags: python, orange, plot

I recently started using  `Orange3` visual for statistical analysis. Most of the interface looks good, however, when I create a scatter plot the axis are so faint I can hardly see them:
[image]

Is there a way I can change the colors of the 'x' and 'y' axis?

Comment: You should re-post this question on StackOverflow. This isn't really about Data Science. You will get an answer faster over there.

Comment: What code are you using to plot this data?

Comment: I don't think that's configurable. If it looks like a bug, report it: https://github.com/biolab/orange3

Comment: @ScottBoston all scatter plots of data have this axis problem when using the `Breeze Dark` theme - opening the `paint data` widget is probably the fastest way to reproduce this as you won't need to import any data.

Comment: @K3---rnc Done: https://github.com/biolab/orange3/issues/3259